# Objects becoming nil when coming back from other view controllers

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

I have @property NSArray in my UIViewController "A" using which data in tableview is generated.
Now user go from UIViewController "A" -> UIViewController "B" through navigation.
Then user go from UIViewController "B" -> UIViewController "C" through navigation.
In UIViewController "C" few function of a custom class are called.

Now when I go back to UIViewController "C" -> UIViewController "B" -> UIViewController "A"

UIViewController "A" shows the same view as before the navigation but that NSArray which was used to generate that view has become nil.

I understand that UIViewController releases objects to free memory but in this case I need this particular NSArray and don't want view controller to release it. so is it possible?

Comment: How did you declare the property? Was it strong or weak?

Comment: You need to show your code so it can be assessed. Show how you are declaring the property, and how you navigate.

Comment: Property is Strong and navigation is through self.navigationController pushViewController

Comment: Are you re-initialising your array in viewDidAppear / viewWillAppear or clearing it in viewWillDisappear / viewDidDisappear? You can confirm if it's instantiating a new view controller instance by logging or setting a breakpoint in viewDidLoad.

Comment: @Nigel : No, initialising is done only once.

Comment: Ok - well, seems like we're going to need some code to help. Or did you fix it?